# Sequence does not match type xs:string error Xquery

Tags: java, xml, database

I am using BDB XML 2.5.16 to store and query my XML  documents in Java. The documents are IMDB xml documents containing actors information obtained from INEX website https://inex.mmci.uni-saarland.de/login.jsp.  One of  the document I stored in the database is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persons>
  <person>
      <name>jason angeles
      </name>
      <filmography>
         <act>
            <movie>
               <title>prison planet 3 the revenge 1998
                </title>
              <year>1998
              </year>
             <character>evil ninja
              </character>
           </movie>
         </act>
      </filmography>
     </person>
     </persons>
```

I want to  search (using XQuery ) for filmography element whose title element contains ANY of the following keywords ('planet', 'revenge', '1998'). Below is the query I used

```
       // declaring function functx:contains-any-of

       String qryRk = "declare namespace functx = 'http://www.functx.com'; " 
        + "declare function functx:contains-any-of "
        + "( $arg as xs:string?" + " , "  + " $searchStrings as xs:string* )   
        as xs:boolean { " + "some $searchString in $searchStrings "
            +  " satisfies contains($arg,$searchString)} ; ";

         String myQuery101 = qryRk + "for $entity in 
           collection('simpleExampleData2.dbxml')//filmography "
              + "where functx:contains-any-of ( $entity/act/movie/title ,                   
             ('planet', 'revenge', '1998'))"
             + "return $entity";
        XmlResults myResults = myManager.query(myQuery101, myContext, null);
        XmlValue myValue = myResults.next();
        if  (myValue == null) System.out.println("No Result");
        System.out.println("Result :   ");
        while (myValue != null){
           XmlDocument myDocument = myValue.asDocument();
           String name  = myDocument.getName();
           String content =  myValue.asString();
           System.out.println("\nDocument : " + name + ": ");
           System.out.println(content);
           myValue = myResults.next();
          }
```

When I  executed the query, I expect to get at least the following **element** as my output

```
                   Document : person_31000.xml:
                <filmography>
                       <act>
                             <movie>
                             <title>prison planet 3 the revenge 1998
                            </title>
                            <year>1998
                            </year>
                           <character>evil ninja
                           </character>
                          </movie>
                       </act>
                     </filmography>
```

However instead of the above element I got the  following Error

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.sleepycat.dbxml.XmlException: Error:    
    Sequence does not match type xs:string? - the sequence contains more   
    than one item [err:XPTY0004], <query>:1:343, errcode =          
    QUERY_EVALUATION_ERROR at                                    
     com.sleepycat.dbxml.dbxml_javaJNI.XmlManager_query__SWIG_0(Native 
    Method)  at 
     com.sleepycat.dbxml.XmlManager.query(XmlManager.java:544)
                             at   

      com.sleepycat.dbxml.XmlManager.query(XmlManager.java:320)
                             at   

      xmlirsystemstruxplus.XQueryEngine.queryEngine(XQueryEngine.java:269)
                             at 

         xmlirsystemstruxplus.XMLIRSystemStruXplus.main(XMLIRSystemStruXplus.java:109)
                             Java Result: 1
```

Note that i used  contains-any-of() function because the contains () function does not work with  'planet revenge 1998' string may be because the keywords do not appear in the order they appear in the element content.

Please  can any body help me to find out 
(1) why i have the  above error ? and solution 
(2)  why  the condition contains  ( $entity/act/movie/title ,  'planet revenge 1998') is not working ? how do i use contains() function w.r.t this

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems you are getting a response with an element of type filmography, which is indeed not a String.

Comment: Thank you. How do I make my query to return d element instead of string?

Comment: Did you somewhere put that the result will be an element of type xs:string?  Check your configuration files.

Comment: which configuration files? pls sorry, I am new to BDB xml database